# nextpeer in cocos2d game

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, nextpeer

I have integrated [nextpeer](http://nextpeer.com)  in cocos2d game.

I used below call to end game. But nextpeer not showing end of game view if game ends within 60 seconds.

```
-(void)callNextPeerTournamentOverWithScore:(int)score
{
    if ([Nextpeer isCurrentlyInTournament])
    {
        [Nextpeer reportControlledTournamentOverWithScore:score];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the type of the tournament? Tournament type should be 'Game Controlled' if you want to end the tournament at any time. You can edit tournament type using their website.

Note: Default tournament type is 60 seconds.

Comment: how can reduce 60 seconds to dynamic depending on game play ?

Comment: Change tournament type to 'Game Controlled' to make it dynamic and place your own timer on your hud layer. In multilayer mode, all players can't set different tournament times to end the whole tournament at same time.

Answer (score 0):

I got solution from shahid-rasheed..Thanks. All we need to do is just change tournament type to 'Game Controlled' in next peer.com not in code.

[image]